# Infinite loop in homework

Tags: c

This is a homework problem which is supposed to print "rinse and repeat" shampoo instructions for n cycles, or an error if n is outside the range 0-4.

Question:
I have found that i have made an infinite loop, but I didn't think I did. I'm confused as to how id accomplish all that with only a few test.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Your solution goes here */
void PrintShampooInstructions(int numCycles) {
    int N = 1.0;
    while ((numCycles > 1 ) && (numCycles < 4)) {
        printf ("%d:Lather and rinse.\n", N);
        ++N;
    }
    if (numCycles < 1) {
        printf ("Too few.\n");
        return;
    } else
    if (numCycles > 4) {
        printf ("Too many.\n");
        return;
    } else {
        printf ("Done.\n");
        return;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    PrintShampooInstructions(2);
    return;
}
```

Comment: @chux I have added it to the end of the code

Comment: `while ((numCycles > 1 ) && (numCycles < 4))
  {
      printf ("%d:Lather and rinse.\n", N);
      ++N;
  }` never changes `numCycles`. Why should it exit?  { I had a washing machine like that once. }

Comment: You have not modified `numCycles` so the loop will be infinite.

Comment: `int N = 1.0` - Back some chapters in the textbook.

Comment: What would I do to stop that then. I know I need it so that it checks those, but i need it to print the steps up until that number. So, would i do something like while (N > 1) && (N < 4)) printf ("%d:Lather and rinse.\n", N); ++N;

Comment: Just how clean do you need your hair to be?

Comment: Suggest trying you idea and see if it works - looks like a good start.

Comment: @pckofwolfs, well it is N that you are changing, so it's probably N you should be checking, but if you want to skip the loop if numCycles >=4, n will always start at 1

Comment: The loop logically goes in the `else` clause, not before the `if`

Comment: This is an interesting variation on the classic ploy to double shampoo sales.  Programmers probably do not read the instructions on the shampoo bottles, otherwise the innocent looking phrase *repeat operation* would have achieved the ultimate marketing achievement: infinite sales.

Comment: Why are you setting `N` to `1.0` and not simply `1`?

Comment: @pckofwolfs: in the question, you state: *an error if n is outside the range 0-4.* but in your implementation, you reject value `0`.  Indeed it seems to make sense that the shampoo be applied at least once. Is the constraint incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop condition is constant, so either the loop is not executed or it keeps executing forever.  Change to code to use a loop is an acceptable number of cycles is requested:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PrintShampooInstructions(int numCycles) {
    if (numCycles < 1) {
        printf("Too few.\n");
        return;
    } else
    if (numCycles > 4) {
        printf("Too many.\n");
        return;
    } else {
        int N = 1;
        while (N <= numCycles) {
            printf("%d: Lather and rinse.\n", N);
            ++N;
        }
        printf("Done.\n");
        return;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    PrintShampooInstructions(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Was in the process of changing it and had something like this. However, I had it so N was < numCycles, and I incremented both N and numCycles making it into a forever integrating loop. Thank you all for the help :D.

Comment: @pckofwolfs: Note that you could use a `for` loop.  The `for` loop is less error prone because the loop index initial, final and increment values are explicit: `for (int N = 1; N <= numCycles; N++) { printf("%d: Lather and rinse.\n", N); }`

Answer (score 1):

What does this snippet do?

```
int N = 1.0;
while ((numCycles > 1 ) && (numCycles < 4))
{
  printf ("%d:Lather and rinse.\n", N);
  ++N;
}
```

It makes the stuff inside the parenthesis {} until the condition becomes false. But the values in the condition never change...